# How could we interpret $\int f'^2\geq \pi^2\int f^2$ and $\int(f'^2+g'^2)\geq \int fg'$ ?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $$X=\left\{g\in W^{1,2}(-1,1)\mid g(1)=g(-1), \int_{-1}^1 g=0\right\}.$$

If $f,g\in X$, how could we interpret geometrically $$\int_{-1}^1 f'^2\geq \pi^2 \int_{-1}^1 f^2$$
and $$\int_{-1}^1(f'^2+g'^2)\geq 2\pi\int_{-1}^1 fg'\ \ ?$$

The first one look like $$\|f'\|_{L^2}\geq \pi\|f\|_{L^2},$$
what could be that the speed is bigger that $\pi$ times the length of $f$... would it make sense ? And for the second one I don't really see a physical interpretation...

Comment: Must there be a physical or geometrical interpretation?

Comment: The first inequality has some resemblance with a form of Heisenberg's inequality:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^2 \leq 2 \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (xf)^2 \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'^2 \right)^{1/2}$$

Answer (score 1):

The inequality (known as Wirtinger's inequality) is essentially equivalent to the *isoperimetric inequality* ($L^2\ge 4\pi A$, where $A$ is the area enclosed by a smooth curve of length $L$). A nice discussion can be found in the article *The Isoperimetric Inequality* by R. Osserman in the Bulletin of the AMS, Nov. 1978.